# Extensible Database Engine;can tables be related

Tags: .net, windows, esent

Can E.S.E tables be related to one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean something like joins or foreign key relations, then no. Each table stands alone and any logic like that has to be provided by the application.